# "hyperledger " Endorser and orderer connections initialized Error: Invalid channel create transaction : mismatched channel ID pharmachannel != chanel

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, pki

Bad configuration detected: Received AliveMessage from a peer with the same PKI-ID as myself: tag:EMPTY alive_msg:<membership:<endpoint:"peer0.consumer.pharma-network.com:13051" pki_id:"\201\023^aX\023^\314\303\304\240N\033\014\005\317\024\334\355\341\263\273\207\010mI\311\341\264/\275." > timestamp:<inc_num:1699540480240058603 seq_num:4 > identity:"\n\013consumerMSP\022\272\006-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Trying to setup my hyperledgerfabric network up but when bootstraping my network i recieve this error up